# Can we simplify a proof of parity equality?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove that the following statements are equivalent: "$m-n$ is even, $m^2-n^2$ is even, and $m^2+n^2$ is even. I know that given a number $x$, $x$ & $x^2$ have the same parity. So is it sufficient to just prove that the sum is even if they have the same parity?

Comment: Note that for all natural numbers $m,n$, it holds that $$m^2+n^2=\left(m^2-n^2\right)+2n^2=(m-n)(m+n)+2n^2.$$

Comment: @GitGud I'm not sure I follow what you are pointing out... this is still even if m & n share the same parity

Comment: The equalities tell you that $m^2+n^2, m^2-n^2$ and $(m-n)(m+n)$ have the same evenness. To get that $m-n$ has the same evenness as the above, consider how the evenness of $m-n$ relates to the evenness of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @GitGud m and n would have to have the same evenness, too

Comment: That's correct. Can you formalize the argument?